# Losing original values while solving inverse trig equations

Tags: trigonometry

While proving, say, that $3tan^{-1}\frac{1}{4} + tan^{-1}\frac{1}{20} = \frac{\pi}{4}- tan^{-1}\frac{1}{1985}.$

There is the possibility that one side would just be n$\pi$ added to the other. So just proving that the tan values of both sides are equal won't be enough, would it? Apparently this method is used a lot

Answer (score 1):

$$(4+i)^3(20+i)(1985+i)$$

$$=(4^3-12+48i-i)(20+i)(1985+i)$$

$$=(52\cdot20-47+i(52+47\cdot20))(1985+i)$$

$$=(993+992i)(1985+i)$$

$$=(993\cdot1985-992+i(992\cdot1985+993))$$

Now $993\cdot1985-992=1985(1+992)-992=992\cdot1985+993$

Finally take argument in both sides

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan\frac{1}{1985}\right)=\frac{1-\frac{1}{1985}}{1+\frac{1}{1985}}=\frac{992}{993}.$$
Now, we can use the same things for the left side:
$$\tan\left(3\arctan\frac{1}{4}+\arctan\frac{1}{20}\right)=\frac{\frac{3\cdot\frac{1}{4}-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3}{1-3\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}+\frac{1}{20}}{1-\frac{3\cdot\frac{1}{4}-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^3}{1-3\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{20}}=\frac{992}{993}.$$
Now,  since $$0<\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan\frac{1}{1985}<\frac{\pi}{4}<\frac{\pi}{2}$$ and $$0<3\arctan\tfrac{1}{4}+\arctan\tfrac{1}{20}<3\arctan(2-\sqrt3)+\arctan(2-\sqrt3)=\tfrac{\pi}{3}<\tfrac{\pi}{2},$$ we obtain our identity.

We see that the case with adding $n\pi$ is impossible here.